# The word/phrase choice in the mentioned sentence?

Tags: phrase-choice, idiomatic-language

> A is not enough for our work. **What more is required** is B.

How is a more idiomatic way to say the bold part in the above sentence?

Answer (score 1):

There is little context so I suggest the simplest possible expression:

> A is not enough for our work. We need B. / We also need B

The fact that B provides "more" is implicit.